# Implementing a SPI to extend Keycloak API - Could not find resource

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-spi

I'm trying to create a custom resource on my Keycloak server to extend its rest API. So i'm implementing a SPI. Starting with a hello world.

At the moment my goal is to obtain a "hello" + name through a GET on http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/hello

I use Postman to requests the server. I'm able to get a user token on myRealm. I choose a user for which i have assigned the role `View-users` in the `realm-managment` Mapper.

So the builtin Keycloak Admin API works. 
e.g :http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/users/count
 returns the expected user count.

But the problem is i get an 
"error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/hello/" when requesting this endpoint.

Here's my setup (i read several guides) :

The module project's pom.xml include dependency for `keycloak-core` `keycloak-server-spi` `keycloak-server-spi-private` `org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs`

RealmResourceProvider implementation :

```
public class HelloWorldProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

    private KeycloakSession session;

    public HelloWorldProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces("text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    public String get() {
        String name = session.getContext().getRealm().getDisplayName();
        if (name == null) {
            name = session.getContext().getRealm().getName();
        }
        return "Hello" + name;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Factory implementation :

```
public class HelloWorldProviderFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

    public static final String ID = "hello";

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int order() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        return new HelloWorldProvider(keycloakSession);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

I also created the file `src\main\resources\META-INF\org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory` it contains a reference to my `HelloWorldProviderFactory`

After packaging the jar, i put a copy of it in `keycloak-9.0.3\standalone\deployments` and after running `standalone.bat` the file `keycloak-spi-rest-hello-1.0.jar.deployed` is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as alexb83 said, i missed the second /hello in the url.

As PotatoesMaster said, i had to omit /admin in the url.

In Addition the file `org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory`
was in a wrong folder : i missed **\services**.

The working path is :

`src\main\resources\META-INF\services\org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/hello/hello

because first 'hello' is the name of your factory ID, instead the second 'hello' is the path you set on the service.

Answer (score 1):

[@alexb83](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3350257/alexb83)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62933441/6045800) does not work for me, I had to omit the `/admin` part from the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myRealm/hello/hello
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to omit `/auth/admin`. So my final worked url is:
http://localhost:8080/realms/master/hello

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had mixed up the order of the sub-paths in the url when accessing the end-point, i.e. instead of

> /user/customuser

I had given

> /customuser/user